# Is $(A \otimes X) \circ (B \otimes Y)$ equal to $AB \otimes XY$ ? If yes, why?

Tags: tensor-products

If $A,B,X,Y$ are linear functions over $V_1$ and $V_2$ vectorial spaces

$A : V_1 \to V_1$

$B : V_1 \to V_1$

$X : V_2 \to V_2$

$Y : V_2 \to V_2$

Comment: Do you understand how $A\otimes X$ acts on the tensor product of two vectors $v_1 \otimes v_2$?

Answer (score 1):

$$(A \otimes X) (v_1 \otimes v_2) = A v_1 \otimes X v_2$$

LHS : $(A\otimes X)(B\otimes Y) (v_1 \otimes v_2) = (A\otimes X)(B v_1 \otimes Y v_2) = AB v_1 \otimes XY v_2$

RHS : $(AB \otimes XY)(v_1 \otimes v_2) = AB v_1 \otimes XY v_2$

If the two expression gives the sames result for any $v_1 \otimes v_2$, by linearity they gives the same result for all elements of the space. Thus they are equal.